# How to add image into collection view cell from saved photo albums?

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I have to make a photo gallery similar to the photos app in iPhone. I have included a collection view to display images. When I click insert image button, the saved photos album of Photos app is displayed(using `UIImagePicker`). But I cannot load the image back to the custom `collectionViewCell`. The `CollectionViewCell` contains an `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [ALAsset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) library.

An ALAsset object represents a photo or a video managed by the Photo application.

Please take a look this tutorial series [“Creating An Image Gallery Like Over](http://www.brandontreb.com/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-an-image-gallery-like-over-part-1/)”.

In this tutorial, you will learn how to actually display the saved photo albums in the UICollectionView.

[image]

Comment: link is broken anyway you can fix it :-)

Comment: @Skovie  fixed it, try this http://www.brandontreb.com/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-an-image-gallery-like-over-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

**You `cellForItemAtIndexPath` for collectionView should look like this.**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //create cel...
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //create UIImageView (declare imageView in header file)
    self.cellImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:"YOUR FRAME"];
    //set image. delete this line if there's no before picking image in uipickercontroller
    [self.cellImageView setImage:"YOUR IMAGE BEFORE USING IMAGEPICKER"];
    [cell addSubView:self.cellImageView];
    return cell;
}
```

**You `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` should look like this...**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    //set image when image is chosen from image picker controller
    self.cellImageView = chosenImage;
    //reload collectionView
    [self.collectionView reloadData];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: I declared imageview in customcell as per my requirement.Whenever am writing as cell.imageview = chosenImage.Am getting issue as use od undeclared identifier "cell".Please guide me.Thanks in advance

Comment: @Vinathynvr : Did you give identifier under inspector view to the object?